# Unsupported operand in TypeT5

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  File "/work/09235/kunjal/ls6/TypeT5/train_model.py", line 112, in <module>
    wrapper = train_spot_model(
  File "/work/09235/kunjal/ls6/TypeT5/typet5/train.py", line 180, in train_spot_model
    trainer.fit(
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 520, in fit
    call._call_and_handle_interrupt(
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/call.py", line 44, in _call_and_handle_interrupt
    return trainer_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 559, in _fit_impl
    self._run(model, ckpt_path=ckpt_path)
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 935, in _run
    results = self._run_stage()
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/trainer/trainer.py", line 978, in _run_stage
    self.fit_loop.run()
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 201, in run
    self.advance()
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/fit_loop.py", line 354, in advance
    self.epoch_loop.run(self._data_fetcher)
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 133, in run
    self.advance(data_fetcher)
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/training_epoch_loop.py", line 218, in advance
    batch_output = self.automatic_optimization.run(trainer.optimizers[0], kwargs)
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 164, in run
    closure = self._make_closure(kwargs, optimizer)
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 197, in _make_closure
    zero_grad_fn = self._make_zero_grad_fn(kwargs.get("batch_idx", 0), optimizer)
  File "/home1/09235/kunjal/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pytorch_lightning/loops/optimization/automatic.py", line 213, in _make_zero_grad_fn
    is_first_batch_to_accumulate = batch_idx % self.trainer.accumulate_grad_batches == 0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

I am trying to run `train_model.py` from https://github.com/utopia-group/TypeT5/blob/master/scripts/train_model.py.
I am getting this error.
How can it be resolved?

Comment: Please include relevant parts of the code (not a link to the code) as well as sample inputs.

Answer (score 0):

`accumulate_grad_batches` is probably `null` or `None` in your lightning config file, change it to
`accumulate_grad_batches:1`